# Extract combination of column names in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe  with columns 'flow1,flow2,flow3' 
I need to extract the different orders I can get from the columns.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Desktop/lab9/cleaning1/1160/flow.tsv", sep = "\t", header = None, na_values=[" "])
df1.columns = ['flow1', 'flow2', 'flow3']
for p in permutations(df1.columns, 3):
    print p
```

This is giving me

```
('flow1', 'flow2', 'flow3')
('flow1', 'flow3', 'flow2')
('flow2', 'flow1', 'flow3')
('flow2', 'flow3', 'flow1')
('flow3', 'flow1', 'flow2')
('flow3', 'flow2', 'flow1')
```

But i just need:

```
('flow1', 'flow2', 'flow3')
('flow1', 'flow3', 'flow2')
('flow2', 'flow3', 'flow1')
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't need the others? The total unique permutations when choosing from 3 alternatives with replacements is 3! = 6, as the function `permutations` gives. Why do you just want those three?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking the math operator.

Use `from itertools import combinations` instead of `permutations`

Comment: You may include :- `[t + tuple(set(df1.columns)-set(t)) for t in combinations(df1.columns, 2)]` to be precise.